# Is there a view or stored procedure that allows knowing privileges user's have over views in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I need to know which views does a user have which privileges on.

I'm searching for something like `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES` or `sp_table_privileges` but for views instead of tables. Is there any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my guess is you want [sys.database_permission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188367.aspx)

```
-- Find permissions granted to current user directly or that are inherited
-- from groups or roles
--
select permission_name from sys.database_permissions
    where grantee_principal_id in
        (
            select user_id()
        union
            select dbp.principal_id from sys.login_token lt, sys.database_principals dbp
                where lt.sid = dbp.sid
        union
            select dbrm.role_principal_id from sys.database_role_members dbrm
                where dbrm.member_principal_id = user_id()
        )
```